# How to launch android wear activity from mobile

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, wear-os

I have been working on a project where I need a button on a mobile to start up an activity on the watch. I have been going through the data layer sample in the sdk but can not get it working. I set up a wearable listener service class, but it is not picking up any messages. The service is added to the manifest but it is still not working. I do have other services too and I am thinking I might have too many services.

On the Wear watch, does an activity have to be running in order for it to start another activity? I want the watch to run nothing until it receives a message, is this possible?

Also, what should my edit configuration settings for wear module be? (eg, do not launch activity, launch default or launch from activity) I just want the wearable to boot up when a message is received.

If anybody can point me in the right direction, it would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**Moblie**

Accessing the Wearable Data Layer

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d("GoogleApi", "onConnected: " + bundle);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d("GoogleApi", "onConnectionSuspended: " + i);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d("GoogleApi", "onConnectionFailed: " + connectionResult);
}
```

GetConnectedNodes

```
Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult getConnectedNodesResult) {
                    for (Node node : getConnectedNodesResult.getNodes()) {
                        sendMessage(node.getId());
                    }
                }
            });
```

SendMessage

```
public static final String START_ACTIVITY_PATH = "/start/MainActivity";


private void sendMessage(String node) {
        Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient , node , START_ACTIVITY_PATH , new byte[0]).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
                if (!sendMessageResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.e("GoogleApi", "Failed to send message with status code: "
                            + sendMessageResult.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**Wear**

Implement a Message Listener

**WearDataLayerListenerService.java**

```
public class WearDataLayerListenerService extends WearableListenerService {
public static final String START_ACTIVITY_PATH = "/start/MainActivity";
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
    if(messageEvent.getPath().equals(START_ACTIVITY_PATH)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this , MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}}
```

**Add Listener Service to Manifest**

```
    <service
        android:name=".WearDataLayerListenerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: @aiur is the path of the activity will be the full path ?

Comment: com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER is deprecated use com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED and 
com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED instead