# Starting android wear app from mobile

Tags: android, wear-os

at the moment it only I can send data between the mobile and wear app while the app is already open on both the mobile and the wear app.  Is there any way that I can start up the wear app from the mobile app instead?

Comment: Could you solve the problem? because the answer only works when the both wear and phone app be open.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch android wear activity from mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050299/how-to-launch-android-wear-activity-from-mobile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement a Message Listener Service,
check this question and my answer

[How to launch android wear activity from mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050299/how-to-launch-android-wear-activity-from-mobile/30067255#30067255)